# How does forwardInvocation: get called?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, forwarding, objective-c-runtime, nsinvocation

Looking only at the Objective-C runtime library, when a message is sent to an object that doesn't respond to it, the runtime system gives the receiver another chance to handle the message. So, the receiver's `forward::` method, if implemented, gets called. However, looking at [NSObject.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm), `NSObject` doesn't seem to implement `forward::`.

So, how does `NSObject`'s `forwardInvocation:` method gets called, since the only thing the runtime system calls when a forwarding is needed is `forward::`? Does Foundation use `objc_setForwardHandler` ([runtime.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/runtime.h)) to set a new handler that calls `forwardInvocation:` whenever a message sent to a `NSObject` object needs to be forwarded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At some point *way back* in time, there was no `NSObject` in the Objective-C runtime. When the language was first created by Brad Cox and Tom Love they added in a root object class, called `Object`. This implemented `[Object forward::]` , which was used to do message forwarding.

A few years later, NextStep came along and made their own additions to the language, creating the OpenStep framework (which became Cocoa). NextStep got rid of the `Object` class, and replaced it with `NSObject`. One of the changes that was made was to replace the `forward::` method with `forwardInvocation`. The `Object` class is still kicking around in the source code (as you have found), but I'm pretty sure it's not available in either iOS or 64 bit OS X apps.

You are correct to suggest that `objc_setForwardHandler` is used to indicate that `forwardInvocation` should be used instead of `forward::` for all `NSObjects`. I am afraid I'm not sure when Foundation calls this...I would guess at `NSObject` initialisation. I am also not massively up on the underlying runtime implementation, but hopefully that will have been of at least *some* help?

Comment: According to an Apple mailing list post from about six years ago ([link here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2007/Oct/msg00036.html)) you can't use `objc_setForwardHandler` unless you're running without foundation. The thread I linked to might have more information that could help you.

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Now I'm sure `Foundation` calls `objc_setForwardHandler` to make `forwardInvocation` get called. If I call `objc_setForwardHandler(NULL, NULL)`, what would override any previously set forward handler, the `forward::` method of my class is called, instead of `forwardInvocation`. So, most surely, on startup, Foundation calls `objc_setForwardHandler` passing `forwardInvocation`'s IMP as arguments.

Comment: You would assume so. I know that the `Cocotron` open source implementation of `Foundation` does it on `NSObject` initialization ([source here](http://cocotron.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Foundation/NSObject/NSObject.m)).

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on `objc_setForwardHandler` shows that it is called from `__CFInitialize` in the CoreFoundation library.

Comment: "but I'm pretty sure it's not available in either iOS or 64 bit OS X apps" What do you mean "not available"?

Comment: @user102008 - it's not included in Foundation or the run-time. GCC also deprecated it and removed any useful methods from their implementation in 2011. If you try and use `Object` when targeting iOS or 64-bit OS X you'll get an error, and XCode will re-direct you to the `NSObject` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574465/objective-c-respondstoselector-question) has a more detailed answer to your question as to what happen when a message is sent to an object that doesn't respond to it.